# Variable that includes an image 'src'

Tags: jquery, html

what i'm trying to do is to declare a variable that include the src="" to an image to save it in database.
so my code is like this :

```
 var newID = $('#RPUserIDTXT').val();
 var newName = $('#RPUsernameTXT').val();
 var newImg = $('#RPUserPicture').src  //Something like this
```

Comment: you can use `$('#RPUserPicture').attr('src');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option: don't use jQuery, src is a property on the DOM object not the jQuery object.

```
var newImg = document.getElementById('RPUserPicture').src
```

---

(Don't do this, jQuery is dead :) If you would like to use jQuery to waste cycles, you have to use [jQuery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 var newImg = $('#RPUserPicture').prop('src')
```

Comment: thank you, it works, could you explain me what is DOM object ?

Comment: Every HTML node in  your document is a DOM (document object model) object. You can see the documentation for the image tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img  jQuery is a wrapper around a collection of HTML nodes.

Answer (score 0):

.src is a property on HTML element, not on jQuery object. jQuery always returns a collection of HTML elements (and some extras). Use eaither

```
var newImg = $('#RPUserPicture').prop('src');
```

or

```
var newImg = $('#RPUserPicture')[0].src; // This throws an error if no objects with given ID are present in the DOM, so jQuery returns an empty list
```

or native javascript:

```
var newImg = document.getElementById('RPUserPicture').src
```